# LIKE on three columns. Show login, firstname ,and lastname on autocomplete list but only select login when user selects

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have this php :

```
$sql = ("SELECT login, firstname, lastname FROM $temp WHERE login LIKE '%$q%'");
$rsd = mysql_query($sql);
while($rs = mysql_fetch_array($rsd)) {
    $login = $rs['login'];
    $fname = $rs['firstname'];
    $lname = $rs['lastname'];
        echo "$login ";
        echo "$fname ";
        echo "$lname \n";
}
```

I have already escaped my variables, etc. I was wondering how I could use LIKE on three columns, how the user would see all three values on the autocomplete list, and then on selecting, would only see the login in the text area. Im using a jquery autocomplete plugin btw:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
    $("textarea#user").autocomplete("autocomplete.php", {
        width: 260,
        matchContains: true,
        selectFirst: false
    });
});
```

Comment: Which plugin are you using? If the plugin allows a functionally where you can query multiple fields in a single file then it will work.

Comment: im using this plugin :  http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL you probably want something like:

```
... where `login` like '...' or `firstname` like '...' or `lastname` like '...'
```

So that any of the three fields will match.

There are a few variations of the jquery.autocomplete plugin. I used one of them and something like the code below works for me well.

```
$("textarea#user").autocomplete("autocomplete.php", {
    width: 260,
    matchContains: true,
    selectFirst: false,
    formatItem: function(row, pos, num, query) {
        // alert(row.join(',')); // See this alert, I don't remember in which order substrings are packed into "row"

        // Return html we want to be displayed in an item within the dropdown list.

        return row[0] + '<br /><em>' + row[1] + '</em> ' + row[2];
    }
}).result(function(event, data, formatted) {
    // alert(data.join(',')) // See what's in the "data", there should be your "login", "firstname", "lastname" of the item selected by user

    // Do what you want here with the event.

    $("textarea#user").val(data[0]);
});
```

I haven't tested the code though.

Also the .result(...) section seems to be unnecessary for your case, autocomplete will insert the first substring of a row into the input, I'm just showing that you can do custom handling of the "item selected" event.

Cheers.

EDIT:

Oh and I forgot you might need two more options for autocomplete:
    matchContains: 'word',
    matchSubset: false,

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use `LIKE` in your query for auto complete.

You would need to do something like this

```
$().ready(function() {
    $("textarea#field1").autocomplete("autocompleteField1.php", {
        width: 260,
        matchContains: true,
        selectFirst: false
    });
});

$().ready(function() {
    $("textarea#field2").autocomplete("autocompleteField2.php", {
        width: 260,
        matchContains: true,
        selectFirst: false
    });
});
```

In your php files you do

```
$sql = ("SELECT DISTINCT firstname FROM $temp WHERE login LIKE '%$q%' LIMIT 0,10");//You don't want to have 20 autocomplete fields
$rsd = mysql_query($sql);
while($rs = mysql_fetch_array($rsd, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        echo "$rs['firstname']";

}
```

The plugin you are using is deprecated. If you haven't worked on it much I would recommend using another plugin which has better support and works pretty well.

This [plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete) is a good one.

For other [jQuery Plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188442/whats-a-good-ajax-autocomplete-plugin-for-jquery).